# Hudson Job not running

Tags: hudson

please help I am stucked. I can compile my project nicely with maven 3.1.0

mvn deploy -Pbuild-int
==> Build success

but if I try to setup a simple Hudson Job to do the same, I am failing all the time an I don`t know why. The error message is unfortunately for a beginner like me not helpful.

I am using a local VirtualSVNServer 2.6.0, a local Hudson Server 3.0.1 and JDK 1.7.0

SVN link and authentication works fine, tested it via providing URL to second browser window and provided details.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

ERROR LOG of the Job

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer anonymous
Updating https://localhost/svn/e2etrace/branches/RB-1.2.0 revision: 19.07.2013 19:56:50 depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision 37
no change for https://localhost/svn/e2etrace/branches/RB-1.2.0 since the previous build
[INFO] Using Maven 3 installation: Maven 3.1.0
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation environment
[workspace] $ D:\maven\bin\mvn.bat --help
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation version
[INFO] Detected Maven 3 installation version: 3.1.0
[workspace] $ D:\maven\bin\mvn.bat deploy -Pbuilt-int -V -B -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\Jonas\.hudson\maven\slavebundle\resources;C:\Users\Jonas\.hudson\maven\slavebundle\lib\maven3-eventspy-3.0.jar;C:\Users\Jonas\.hudson\war\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\hudson-remoting-3.0.0.jar -Dhudson.eventspy.port=54334 -f pom.xml
[DEBUG] Waiting for connection on port: 54334
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 04:15:32+0200)
Maven home: D:\maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.hudsonci.maven.eventspy_30.DelegatingEventSpy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/guice/bean/reflect/ClassSpace
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1891)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.EntryListAdapter$ValueIterator.next(EntryListAdapter.java:111)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:141)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:151)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.setEventSpies(EventSpyDispatcher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.reflect.BeanPropertySetter.set(BeanPropertySetter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.binders.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:128)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:134)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:420)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.ClassSpace
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 78 more
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting: public void org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.setEventSpies(java.util.List)
  at ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
  while locating org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher
  roleHint: 
[ERROR] Caused by: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting: public void org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.setEventSpies(java.util.List)
  at ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
  while locating org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher

1 error
[ERROR] Caused by: org/sonatype/guice/bean/reflect/ClassSpace
[ERROR] Caused by: org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.ClassSpace

[ERROR] Process did not initiate connection and appears to have died; exit code: 1
[ERROR] Failure: hudson.AbortException: Process did not initiate connection and appears to have died; exit code: 1
ERROR: Process did not initiate connection and appears to have died; exit code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven Home variable was wrong. Sometimes thinks are so obvious. Be aware use / instead \ and I left out disk. Now it works.

Comment: What exactly was wrong with the Maven Home variable? I'm seeing this issue and I don't understand how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the bundled (in the plugin it seems) maven 3 installation in favor to a manual installed one.

So I don't need to add a maven installation in the hudson configuration.